Why are my zucchini and lima beans new plants yellowing? and somewhat curling what can I use for spider mites on new plants and peas
I have zucchini Lima and peas new plants about 12 in some maybe 8 to 10 in. In pot still. On an uninsulated porch but it's closed in. My leaves are starting to yellow and the water doesn't seem to be drying much I'm watering a little bit from the bottom every other day if that because it's not drying fast. I do believe I got some spider mites or a little black bugs maybe I don't know if it's dirt. What can I spray on new plants to get rid of any kind of pests. I tried neem oil before my house plants and they turned black and died. I do keep a fan on them and there is air conditioning on the porch but it's always on like 70 it's not cold in here at all I do take them outside too several days a week okay

You should add a picture to your post.  When was the last time you fed them?

Neem oil is mild, but you did dilute it greatly, didn't you?
